# Reverse a linked list without using a pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have successfully implemented the 2 pointers solution using this code:

```
void list_reverse(t_list **begin_list)
{
    t_list *new_root;
    t_list *root;
    t_list *next;

    new_root = 0;
    root = *(begin_list);
    while (root)
    {
        next = root->next;
        root->next = new_root;
        new_root = root;
        root = next;
    }
    *begin_list = new_root;
}
```

Which works fine - at least according to my tests. Now I want to try to reverse a linked list using only a single pointer, without `return`, so I tried to convert my code to `void list_reverse(t_list *begin_list)`, but of course the `*begin_list = new_root` doesn't work, because I can't change `begin_list`. The rest seems to work though.

How can I modify `begin_list` without a double pointer?

Edit: Structure is :

```
typedef struct  s_list
{
    struct s_list   *next;
    void            *data;
}               t_list;
```

Comment: Did you try to do it using recursion?

Comment: Modifications to function arguments are not visible to the function caller.  Not in the code you present, either. (Your function changes the object its argument *points to*, which the caller happens also to be able to see; that's not the same thing.)  But you can provide the modified pointer to the caller via the function's return value.

Comment: It is impossible because it can not change the first element. (Except when making the first element dummy.)

Comment: Recursion is quite beside the point, @hbagdi.  Recursive and iterative approaches are both possible, and both have the issue the OP is asking about: providing a modified pointer value to the caller.

Comment: @JohnBollinger _without **return**_

Comment: Yeah the return was my idea but the contraint is to not use it, which is confusing to me because it just seems impossible

Comment: I haven't touched C (or any language with pointers for that matter) for a while, so feel free to correct me, but I don't see how that can be possible, at least in O(n). Sure, you can recurse and do it in O(n^2), but that's quite a difference. To reverse a singly linked list you need to get to the last element and put it on front (say, of a temporary list), but what's more troubling you than need to go one step backwards which would actually require you to traverse the list again

Comment: ok only now I've read that it's the constraint, so I assume it's some kind of an assignment. God I hated those. Sure, it's possible, make n traversions to the (n-1)th member, save them in that order in a new list and reassign the pointer to point to the new list. I suppose that could work?

Comment: Yeah, don't we all love to mess around with pointers? I'll give your idea a go, it seems logical!

Comment: So, @Luke, if you package all that up in a function, how do you then solve the OP's main problem -- providing the new list head to the caller?

Comment: Yeah, i tried to push values to a new list, but it doesn't change the issue, i can't remotely change the head value ...

Comment: @JohnBollinger you've got a pointer to the pointer as an argument. Could you change the pointer it points to, to point to the new list? If that makes any sense haha

Comment: So, you're restricted to a `void` return. How many function parameters are you permitted?

Comment: @Luke, you're missing the whole point.  The OP knows how to do it with the pointer-to-pointer already.  The question is how to do it with a (single) pointer directly to a list node: "How can i modify begin_list ***wihthout a double pointer*** ?" (emphasis added).

Comment: @JohnBollinger right I figured it out now, I was looking at the code the whole time, nvm

Comment: Ok, so i found *a* solution, i basically use the array reverse method, going from i = 0 to i = len / 2, and swapping the i-th value with the (len - i - 1)th value. It's horrible, but it works, so if you have anything better..... ;D

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I have to use the prototype that is in the question, void list_reverse(t_list *begin_list)

Comment: You've not shown the structure definition, so people can't reliably write code to implement the 'swap values instead of pointers' code.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that, i've edited the question

Comment: I edited the title to explain what you mean by "a single pointer". I thought you wanted to get rid of the three local pointers that you declared.

Comment: @Rogue - this is where a doubly-linked list provides a distinct advantage, simply iterate in reverse (with a circular list, you can iterate fwd/rev from any node as head/tail are no different than any other node). For your current question, you have two very good answers for guidance.

Answer (score 6):

You can reverse the list by swapping the first and the last node in place (shallow copy), then reversing the list. This way the *content* of the last node would end up in the initial node, to which the head pointer is already pointing.

Here is an implementation:

```
void swap(struct node *a, struct node *b) {
    struct node tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void reverse(struct node *h) {
    // Null list and single-element list do not need reversal
    if (!h || !h->next) {
        return;
    }
    // Find the last node of the list
    struct node *tail = h->next;
    while (tail->next) {
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    // Swap the tail and the head **data** with shallow copy
    swap(h, tail);
    // This is similar to your code except for the stopping condition
    struct node *p = NULL;
    struct node *c = tail;
    do {
        struct node *n = c->next;
        c->next = p;
        p = c;
        c = n;
    } while (c->next != tail);
    // h has the content of tail, and c is the second node
    // from the end. Complete reversal by setting h->next.
    h->next = c;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/QUTf8M)

Answer (score 4):

There are three main ways in which a function can provide a computed value to its caller.

1. It can `return` that value, or an object containing it, or a pointer to such an object (provided, in the last case, that the pointed-to object outlives the function call).
2. It can modify an object visible to the caller via a pointer provided by the caller.
3. It can record the computed value in a file-scope variable visible to the caller.

There are other alternatives, mostly involving I/O, but those are generally in the spirit of (3).

You are not permitted to use (1).  You cannot use (2) in the way you propose.  It may be that (3) is the expected answer, but that's ugly, and really should not be recommended.  So what to do?

Maybe you just bite the bullet and use a file-scope variable, but if you're permitted to enlist the aid of the caller and / or place a requirement on the form of the list then you have another possibility: have the caller pass a pointer that does not change when the list is reversed -- i.e. a pointer to a structure that contains a pointer to the list head.  The function does not then need to modify that pointer; it returns the new list head via the pointed-to object.

Oftentimes one does that sort of thing with a separate structure type representing the whole list.  If you think for a moment, however, you will realize that your existing list node type already has suitable form.  If you are unable to introduce a new structure, then, you can use your existing one -- just treat the first node in the list as a non-data-bearing handle on the rest of the elements.  This is sometimes called a dummy head node, and lists that use one afford simpler function implementations in many respects.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
void reverse(struct node* head) {
    struct node *curr=head; 
    struct node *next=NULL;
    struct node *prev=NULL; 
    while(curr) { 
        next=curr->next; //we're basically stashing the next element
        curr->next=prev; //setting next pointer to the previous element
        prev=curr; //previous is now current
        curr=next; //and updating the current from the stashed value
    }
}
```