# Pthread exit and pthread join

Tags: c, pthreads

I want to create a thread from function 1 to execute function 2. To get the status of completion of function 2 to function 1, what I need to do? Is pthread_exit mandatory in function 2 to return back the status variable to function 1?

Also should return type of function 2 be void*? What can be the type of variable status ( eg. I want to use BOOL)  then?

Comment: Why not just call it in the same thread? Are you intending to do anything in parallel?

Comment: What does your code look like? In what way does it not work?

Comment: Your thread function (`function2()`) can return or call `pthread_exit()` — both work.  The return type should be a void pointer.

Comment: Yes. I am using 2 threads. And I want the result or any data from the function I call from thread to return back to calling function.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a thread from function 1 to execute function 2. To
>   get the status of completion of function 2 to function 1, what I need
>   to do?

You have basically the same [three alternatives a function has for providing a computed value to a caller in the same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45271082/2402272).  For a single return value of pointer or integer type, however, the thread's return value is a particularly convenient way to provide such a value.  You do, however, have the added complication of ensuring that the child thread finishes before you try to obtain the value.  You would use `pthread_join()` for that part.

> Is pthread_exit mandatory in function 2 to return back the
>   status variable to function 1?

No.  A thread also exits when a `return` statement is executed in the initial call to its thread function.  This is equivalent to passing the specified return value as the argument to `pthread_exit()`.  Returning from the call is a bit cleaner in my book, but `pthread_exit()` has the advantage that a thread can call it from any place in any function.

> Also should return type of function 2 be void*?

You not only can, but ***must*** declare the return value of your thread function to be `void *`.  This is an essential part of such a function's type, and you invoke undefined behavior if you try to use a thread start function with a different return type.

> What can be the type
>   of variable status ( eg. I want to use BOOL) then?

C has no type named "BOOL".  It has `_Bool` and other integer type, and if you use `stdbool.h` then it has the macro `bool` as an alternative spelling of `_Bool`.  You have several alternatives as to how to return such a value from your thread; one would be to cast it to `void *` and have the parent thread cast the result back.  Another would be to use `NULL` to represent false and any other value or values to represent true.  If you wish, you can use those values directly in C conditional expressions without casting.

Comment: Thank you :) it's really helpful for me .